# How to display the day of the week on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to automatically display the day of the week on a button?

See the markup below, I need to make "Monday" show whatever day of the week it is.

```
<button class="button">Conquer Monday</button>
```

Comment: can you using js

Comment: What have you tried and where specifically are you stuck?  Are you able to get the current day of the week in JavaScript?  Update an element's text in JavaScript?  What isn't working in your attempt?

Comment: I have read a number of posts about using "getDay()" but Im unsure how to use this with HTML to display the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Date::toLocaleDateString` to display the current week day:

```js
document.querySelector('.button').textContent = 'Conquer ' + new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-us', {weekday:'long'});
```

```html
<button class="button"></button>
```

Comment: it's not logic show today before click in button ??

Comment: @XMehdi01 there's nothing in the question about setting the text on the button's click. the OP just wants to display the text in the button immediately on the page load i guess

Comment: We as developers have to do it on our own
Everything should not be expected from the owner of the problem

Answer (score 1):

can you using this code js using `Date().getDay()` return day of week between 0 and 6 and `weekdays` list of day of week

```js
//get button with id
  const button = document.getElementById("dayButton");
  // array of day
  const weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  //Indice day
  const currentDayiIndex = new Date().getDay();
  //Show day in click the button
    dayButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        day.innerHTML = weekdays[currentDayiIndex]
        button.innerHTML = "Conquer " + weekdays[currentDayiIndex];
        })
```

```html
<button class="button" id="dayButton">Show Day</button>
<p id="day"></p>
```

I hope I helped you

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what Im trying to achieve. But I need the day (Thursday for example) to appear on the button itself, not below the button once clicked.

Comment: i fixed my code check my code